# can I set Roaming Profiles to create folders and permissions on a new pc they are used on?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, roaming-profile

hopefully a quick question, we run roaming profiles on Server 2008 R2 to allow desk hot swapping. At the moment, because of some of the software packages running, we have to manually set the user as a local admin, create various internet explorer trusted sites and install some active-x controls for a web based package.

I am wondering if there is a way to speed this up by happening automatically when the user is logged on for the first time? I imagine this can be done through a Group Policy but must admit I'm not sure where to even start looking as I haven't used it very much before!

thanks in advance!

Comment: Just as a word of advice, I would advise against running local admin unless it's absolutely necessary. Follow the security practice of "The rule of least privilege" and you'll save yourself a lot of potential headaches that local admin can bring (unwanted software, malware, the ability for users to play with disks and network settings, etc).

Comment: I am aware that setting everyone as local admin is not ideal, but sadly a couple of the software packages we use need us to set all users as local admin or we will run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

1) Local Admins - do this using a security group and Group Policy Preferences

2) Trusted Sites - group policy again

3) ActiveX Control - depends exactly what it is and how it installs. May be one for a script.

Please don't cop out and bodge it, the first two are EXACTLY what Group Policy / Preferences were built for. You're using cutting edge server technology, so utilise it! There are loads of resources on the net to start off with.

Comment: I'll have a look into using security groups for the local admins, also I am not sure how to add trusted sites into group policy but will try and find that too. also how would the script be worded to install active-x controls? thanks

Comment: Perhaps this will help with your GPO http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/configure-trusted-sites-internet-explorer-group-policy/

Comment: Added the trusted sites in quite happily! I will do some checks tomorrow morning but all looking good so far. Thanks for that, I get a bit lost in Group Policy sometimes :s

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be to try a logon script.

Comment: but i don't need it running every time someone logs on, only the first time to set the initial settings. Also i am not sure of the commands to set any of the things i need to do, so if you do know, le me know and i could give it a test. cheers

Comment: Then add some logic that checks if the necessary steps are already done and skip them if this is the case.

Comment: sorry just added to previous comment, i will have a look into logic commands for the bat file